Iterate 2 unequal items using ansible loop
I'm trying to iterate 2 lists through Ansible. First is a static variable with 2 items, second is a register variable with 25 items.
static_variable :
  - 1 
  - 2

register variable (got from an output)
first_commmand_output:
 - one
 - two
 - .
 - .
 - twenty five

I'm expecting 1 (static variable) to iterate all 25 registered variables (one at a time) and 2 to do the same.
However, while using product filter, 1 instead of iterating 1 to 25 (one at a time), iterates it all at once. This is not desired as I need to pass this output as an argument to another command.
---
- name: To get the list of first command
  shell: ./mqcli.py -a {{ item }} "some command" | awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}' 
  loop: "{{ static_variable }}" 
  register: first_commmand_output

# first task runs as expected

- name: To run second command based on first's output
  shell: ./mqcli.py -a {{ item.0 }} "listcert -m "{{ item.1.stdout_lines }}"" 
  loop: "{{ static variable | product(first_command_output.results) | list }}"
  register: second_command_output
  
#  requiring assistance for the 2nd 


What is the expected result? Shorten the second list to 'three'. See [mre].

Given the variables
  svar: [1, 2]
  dvar: [one, two, three]

declare the data
  data: "{{ dict(svar | product([{'dvar': dvar}])) }}"

gives
  data:
    1:
      dvar: [one, two, three]
    2:
      dvar: [one, two, three]

In the loop, convert the dictionary to list and iterate subelements
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ data | dict2items | subelements('value.dvar') }}"

gives (abridged)
  msg: 1 one
  msg: 1 two
  msg: 1 three
  msg: 2 one
  msg: 2 two
  msg: 2 three



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    svar: [1, 2]
    dvar: [one, two, three]
    data: "{{ dict(svar | product([{'dvar': dvar}])) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: data | to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ data | dict2items | subelements('value.dvar') }}"



Working fine, thank you!!
